# OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\python311\\scripts\\pip.exe' Consider using the `--user` option

Tags: python, authentication, installation, pip, version

I was trying to upgrade my pip version but this error keep coming after vary efforts I used "  python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip" to upgrade my pip and tried to use --user option but it seems to require a permission and which I am unable to resolve.

I tried to go to my C drive and then Python installation folder and after that Properties and Security and from there I tried to change the Authentication to "Full control" but no luck as such. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried with --user in an admin console?